# does php try catch catches mongodb and symfony errors?

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I'm using symfony2 and mongodb. I'm not using anything for mongodb besides the php driver.
My question is, if symfony or mongodb throw an exception, does:

```
try {
   //some code to be excecuted
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    logToDb($e->getMessage());
}
```

Work as it should(the code in try fails for some reason and $e->getMessage() contains the error)

Thanks for the help
Regards.

Comment: Well ... why dont you test it?

Comment: i`ve tested it and it doesnt log anything. This snippet of code is executed by a payment provider, so its not accessible from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

it works like it should. if you throw an exception in controller then Symfony will show you a proper template for this. It's nothing extra ordinary.

Please also check if the code in try block is throwing an exception. It's really popular mistake.

Regards, 
Piotr

Comment: This snippet of code is executed by a payment provider, so its not accessible from the browser.

Comment: So, maybe it's not throwing the exception? Have you checked it?

Comment: yes, i have checked it, and the exception isn`t thrown nor is the code in the try block executed.

Comment: SO maybe there's your answer - to catch an exception something has to throw it.

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was a foolish mistake by my side - logic mistake. Thank you for the time. I`ll remove my question.

Comment: Don't remove it. It may help somebody.